# Flash Animate - Webview Scale/Zoomfactor

Tags: android, flash, webview, size, scale

so i have a question about open websites with the webView.loadURL function. On ios the scale factor seems to be perfect, and the page fits perfect to the Rectangle I create to visualize the page. But if i create a build for andorid, the website opens with the maximum of zoom, so I have to tap into the screen and zoom out to see the complete page.

Has someone an idea how to determine the automatic zoom on android? It would be great if I load the page, and it would be showed completely, without a zoomfactor like on ios.

To change the size of the rectangle wouldn't be a solution, because I have a fix size, and I need to keep it.

Best regards and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully it is not too late and hopefully this time it will be useful.
Try adding an element into the dom like this:

```
var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();

webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, this.stage.stageWidth, this .stage.stageHeight); 

webView.stage = this.stage; 

var htmlString:String = "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>";

webView.loadString( htmlString );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the source code of the website, try to write this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />`

Comment: Hy Raul, thanks for your answer. 
Unfortunately i cant access the source code - or better - iam not sure how to do this. Would there be a solution i could code right into my as3 script? Like on the part where i initialize the webview? This would be great.